# Creation of forms in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to add forms in Wordpress websites and I have seen many plugins. It's not satisfactory to create forms with proper dimensions in a page and I am not getting proper look with few forms. Could you please suggest any solution for this. I am happy to add any kind of plugin.

Comment: I use Gravity Forms extensively https://www.gravityforms.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create forms in many ways, if you want to add colors or dements you need to edit CSS
and  you can find it on most of the plugins and some themes have inbuilt form plugins. You can
explore them.

General steps for any kind of form inclusions:

Log into your WordPress admin dashboard.
Install a form plugin for WordPress.
Create a new form.
Add fields to your new contact form.
Embed your form onto a Contact Us page.

If you want a third-party  plugin for a separate database; you can install jot forms and there are complete list of instructions over there.

Please refer the following Links:

https://www.gravityforms.com/create-form-wordpress/

https://www.jotform.com/